# Adsense earnings much better after trying a different network?

Tags: google-adsense

My adsense earnings were pretty stable for a few months with a consistent cpc and rpm. I experimented with a different ad network because I wasn't really satisfied with my earnings. After the second network wasn't really performing great either, I decided to switch back to adsense and noticed that my cpc and rpm has been much higher. What caused this change? Obviously, I would like to prolong this as much as possible.

Comment: Do you want us guess ? well, my guess is that during the time that passed your website earned more traffic which increased your revenue. but if you want a *real* answer - better start using google-analytics and you'll be able to analyze traffic on your website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for anyone to know what brought about this change. it could have been more traffic to your site, more people clicking ads, or a change in the way Google was calculating the amounts.

I wouldn't think it was related to you trying out another ad network though, because if it was that easy to get increased advertising dollars people would be doing it all the time. they'd just switch to one network, then back again, as many times as they could.

Using a tool like Google Analytics would really help you understand the traffic and visitors to your site.